# Codecademy Race Day else statment isn't working

Tags: if-statement

Here's my code for this test project. My else statement isn't returning when my age is set to 18. Ignore the change in double/single quotes; I accidentally clicked on the Clean Up button and Codecademy switched them.

```
let raceNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
const early = true;
const age = 18;

if (early && age > 18) {
  raceNumber += 1000;
  console.log("Your race starts at 9:30am, and your number is " + raceNumber + ".");
} else if (!early && age > 18) {
  console.log("Your race starts at 11:00am, and your number is " + raceNumber + ".");
} else if (early || !early && age < 18) {
  console.log('Your race starts at 12:30pm, and your number is ' + raceNumber + '.');
} else {
  console.log('Please see the registration desk for your race time and number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `early` is always true, then `early || !early && age < 18` is true, and the final else will never be reached.

You might be in need of some parentheses